# I try to fetch data from firbase but I get this error.The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, snapshot

'''
QuestionModel getQuestionModelFromDatasnapshot(
DocumentSnapshot questionSnapshot) {
QuestionModel questionModel = new QuestionModel();

```
questionModel.question = questionSnapshot.data()'question'];

List<String> options = [
  questionSnapshot.data()["option1"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option2"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option3"],
  questionSnapshot.data()["option4"]
];
options.shuffle();

questionModel.option1 = options[0];
questionModel.option2 = options[1];
questionModel.option3 = options[2];
questionModel.option4 = options[3];
questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot.data()["option1"];
questionModel.answered = false;

print(questionModel.correctOption.toLowerCase());

return questionModel;
```

}

'''

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using dart with null safety on and you are accessing a list or map that might be null. It's hard to tell from your code, but I'm guessing the offending line is

```
questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot.data()["option1"];
```

It might be one of the other [] calls earlier in your code (such as
`questionSnapshot.data()["option1"]`), but the solution is the same.
The problem is that **questionSnapshot.data()** might return null, and the compiler is flagging it.

If you are sure the data is not null, you can use the `!` operator, like this:

```
questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot.data()!["option1"];
```

Another solution is a conditional null-safe operator `?`, with a default value. In this case, the code would look like this:

questionModel.correctOption = questionSnapshot.data()?["option1"]??"DefaultValue;

But I would recommend checking if the returned data is null. It's easier for others to read and can be logged more easily:

```
var data = questionSnapshot.data();
if (data != null) {
  questionModel.correctOption = data["option1"];
}
else {
  //do something in that case
}
```